# Trace Distance of Joint probability Distribution

Tags: probability

Since we define Trace distance between two probability distributions as:
$$ D(P,Q) =\frac12 \sum_j|P(x_j)-Q(x_j)| $$
I couldn't find the equation for when there are two joint probability distributions say $P(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y)$
any ideas?

Comment: A joint probability distribution for 2 RVs $U$ and $V$ is just a single probability distribution for the joint random variable $(U,V)$.  To put it another way: why doesn't the formula you give already apply to joint probability distributions?

Comment: @JacobManaker I guess my question wasn't clear. The formula I wrote was for two probability distribution that both have one random variable, what is the formula for when   two other probability distributions have two random variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total variation distance between two distributions $P$ and $Q$ on two joint random variables is

$$D(P,Q) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}|P(x_i,y_j)-Q(x_i,y_j)|$$